# Add up values from table columns in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Is it possible in PostgreSQL to select one column from a table within a particular date span (there is a date column) and - here is the catch! - add the table together. Like for making a sales report?

Comment: Can you post an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: @RedFilter absolutely. two minutes.

Comment: `SELECT amount FROM sales_orders WHERE date BETWEEN 11-03-06 & 11--04-06` and add them together...

Comment: `INSERT INTO tbl_a SELECT date_fld FROM tbl_b WHERE CAST(date_fld AS DATE) BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-31'` but it sounds you may want a join?

Comment: @MrAnderson thanks no i don't think i need a join; the date and amount values are in the same table..

Comment: @thomas: Don't hide essential details in the comments. Please edit your question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, I think you are referring to `SUM()`.  This is an [aggregate](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/currentinteractive/functions-aggregate.html) function

```
SELECT SUM(amount)
FROM sales_orders 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2011-03-06' and '2011-04-06' -- not sure what your date is.
```

Comment: oops..meant to post this comment to you : razorsql asked me to enter a parameter value for & ..what does that mean?

Comment: @thomas you need to use `AND` between your dates not `&`.

Comment: @thomas you need to place you dates in the correct format `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: Please link to the current version of the manual. [Postgres 8.1 has been out of business for quite a while now.](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) If you don't need to address a particular version, it's probably best to point to  [`http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108714/169168).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter agreed.  That was the link I got when I tried to find aggregate function.  I should have verified it was functioning when I posted. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: To be clear, the old manual for 8.1 is still there, and will be for the forseeable future. The Postgres people also added a feature in the header of the manual recently to display available versions. But it leads to confusion and encourages Google to keep coughing up ancient links, since they are being reused over and over.

Comment: @erwin I will keep that in mind. It is not a normal tag for me to answer in.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for this:

```
SELECT sum(amount) 
FROM sales_orders 
WHERE date ...
```

Comment: my razorsql asked me to enter a parameter value for &  ..what does that mean?